# Is there an easy method to use ECS for abilities? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox, entity-component-system

I'm a Roblox developer and so I know this probably isn't the best place to ask, but I've been learning about ECS the past week and I'm now trying to use it in a project that has classes with different abilities and I'm curious to know how to implement that using ECS or if it's even a good idea to use ECS in the first place.

*Note: There is a Roblox ECS library called Matter which is what I'm using*

This is my player entity which is created when the player joins and it has an `AbilityUser` component with 3 abilities they can do.

```lua
-- Player Entity
World:spawn(
    Components.AbilityUser({
        possibleAbilities = {
            "GuardRush",
            "GaleSlashes",
            "EtherealWhirlWind",
        },
        activeAbilites = {
            
        }
    }),
)
```

I then have an ability/input system to check for when an ability key is pressed which will then make the ability as an entity adding the ability component with a reference to the player entity and a tag for what the ability is which is grabbed from the AbilityUser component.

```lua
local function AbilitySystem(world)
    for id, abilites, input in world:query(Components.AbilityUser, Components.Input) do     
        for _, inputObject, gp in Matter.useEvent(UIS, "InputBegan") do
            if inputObject.KeyCode == input.Keys.Ability1 then
                world:spawn(
                    Components.Ability({owner = id}),
                    Components[abilites.possibleAbilities[1]]()
                )
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

And then lastly systems for each ability to do the logic. So essentially I'm using the ability entities as events which I don't think is an ideal use? This has been the only method I've figured out that feels right though.